# Automatically load a div at a particular time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a countdown timer which displays at a start date/time and collapses a div at end date/time. My issue is the countdown timer does not display if I'm already on the page before the countdown starts till I refresh the page. How do I make the counter automatically display if I was already on the page before the start time. Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };                
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    //display countdown
    document.getElementById("event").style.display = 'block';               
    var cHours = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.hours');
    var cMinutes = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.minutes');
    var cSeconds = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var tr = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    //add Zero to values
    cHours.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.hours).slice(-2);
    cMinutes.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.minutes).slice(-2);
    cSeconds.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (tr.total <= 0) {                    
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }

  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


//set start and end date
var deadline = ['May 18 2018 13:01:00 GMT-5','May 18 2018 22:29:00 GMT-5'];          

  var startDate = deadline[0];
  var endDate = deadline[1];

  // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
  var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
  var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
  var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

  // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
  if (endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs ){                  
      initializeClock('event', endDate);                   
  }else{
    document.getElementById("event").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="event">
    <div id="countdownHolder">                  
       <div>                     
          <h3><strong><span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span></strong><br> Save up to 25% before time runs out.</h3>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="test">
        <h1>Hide the entire event section at 00:00:00</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>                
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in this case is start another interval that checks if its time to initialize your clock. I wrapped your code in another function and call it every 3 seconds to check if its time to initialize your clock.

Users that are already on the page will get this update within x seconds of it going live.

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  //display countdown
  document.getElementById("event").style.display = 'block';
  var cHours = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.hours');
  var cMinutes = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.minutes');
  var cSeconds = document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var tr = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    //add Zero to values
    cHours.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.hours).slice(-2);
    cMinutes.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.minutes).slice(-2);
    cSeconds.innerHTML = ('0' + tr.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (tr.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }

  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var checkStartInterval = setInterval(checkIfStartTime, 3000);

function checkIfStartTime() {
  //set start and end date
  var deadline = ['May 18 2018 13:01:00 GMT-5', 'May 18 2018 22:29:00 GMT-5'];

  var startDate = deadline[0];
  var endDate = deadline[1];

  // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
  var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
  var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
  var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

  // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
  if (endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs) {
    initializeClock('event', endDate);
    clearInterval(checkStartInterval);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("event").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="event">
  <div id="countdownHolder">
    <div>
      <h3><strong><span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span></strong><br> Save up to 25% before time runs out.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <h1>Hide the entire event section at 00:00:00</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```